# How can i update my existing image in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image, append

well first i need to display the existing image that comes from API in react native.
then i need to update the existing image and replace with new picture.

Code:

```
 <FlatList
              data={filePath}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
              renderItem={({item}) => {
                setImageName(item.fileName);
                setImageType(item.type);
                setImageUri(item.uri);
                return (
                  <View>
                    <Image source={{uri: item.uri}} style={styles.imageStyle} />
                  </View>
                );
              }}
            />
```

button where i set my new picture

```
<GlobalButton
            onPress={() => {
              chooseFile('photo');
            }}
            text={'Add Image'}
          />
```

```
 const chooseFile = type => {
    let options = {
      mediaType: type,
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      quality: 1,
    };
    launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        showError('User cancelled camera picker');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
        showError('Camera not available on device');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
        showError('Permission not satisfied');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
        showError(response.errorMessage);
        return;
      }
      setFilePath(response.assets);
    });
  };
```

i get the image uri from API . i have showed it in return but it shows me two picture the existing one and new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> well first you need to make a state and set it to true like this one

```
const [newImageSelected, setNewImageSelected] = useState(false)
```

> when you pick a new image from image picker then set this state to
> true

```
const chooseFile = type => {
    let options = {
      mediaType: type,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      quality: 1,
    };
    launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        showError('User cancelled camera picker');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
        showError('Camera not available on device');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
        showError('Permission not satisfied');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
        showError(response.errorMessage);
        return;
      }
      setFilePath(response.assets);
      setNewImageSelected(true);
    });
  };
```

> then in return write set the condition if image is already existed
> then it only shows the one picture which you are getting from the. and
> when you select the new image the existing image replaced with the new
> one check the below code maybe it helps you:

```
{newImageSelected ? (
              <FlatList
                data={filePath}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                  setImage(item.fileName);
                  setImageUri(item.uri);
                  setImageType(item.type);
                  return (
                    <View>
                      <Image
                        source={{uri: item.uri}}
                        style={styles.imageStyle}
                      />
                    </View>
                  );
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={{uri: `existing image URL`}}
                style={styles.imageStyle}
              />
            )}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update your screen with your data , you need to use `state`

To understand how it works first refer this link so you can understand how it works and how you can use it

https://reactnative.dev/docs/state.html

After that you can check how flatlist work because as per your code , you are not much aware with react native ..

FlatList accept array as data not object

here you can refer documentation

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist